# How to show a triangle image in an html tree

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use this tree:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp
Can someone tell me what part of the code shows the triangle image being shown with every expandable li? I would like to reduce the size of it, but I cant figure out where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the part:

```css
.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

The `\25B6` is the unicode for the triangle.

Comment: this it the answer I was looking for. Thanks. Someone gave a -1 to me. hmmmm

Answer (score 1):

Styles:

```css
.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6"; //Unicode for the triangle
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.caret-down::before { //Adding this class rotates the element to point down
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */'
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}
```

and usage:

```html
<span class="caret">Beverages</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect carrets, you will see caret-down when expended and just carret on initial state. In css inspector you should see, .caret-down::before and .caret::before css. These are the css that draws triangles.